# Perl Digest Bcrypt, generating a proper hash

Tags: perl, bcrypt

I have written a test program that generates a Bcrypt hash. This hash later needs to be verified by a PHP backend.

This is my perl code:

```
use Digest;
#use Data::Entropy::Algorithms qw(rand_bits);


#my $bcrypt = Digest->new('Bcrypt', cost=>10, salt=>rand_bits(16*8));
my $bcrypt = Digest->new('Bcrypt', cost=>10, salt=>'1111111111111111');
my $settings = $bcrypt->settings(); # save for later checks.
my $pass_hash = $bcrypt->add('bob')->b64digest;
print $settings.$pass_hash."\n";
```

This prints

```
$2a$10$KRCvKRCvKRCvKRCvKRCvKOoFxCE1d/OZTKQqhet3bKOq6ZVIACXBU
```

This does not validate as a proper hash if I use an online bcrypt tool such as https://bcrypt-generator.com

Can someone point out the error? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try without the salting?

Comment: Thanks, looks like I was using the wrong function. Who knew.

Comment: Take note of https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::Bcrypt#NOTICE.

Comment: Yes, thanks Grinnz. Did read that and may migrate to that module in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the problem. I have to use `bcrypt_b64digest` instead of `b64digest`. I wish the perl documentation was clearer in which one needs to be used so that other bcrypt implementations can "get it".

```
my $pass_hash = $bcrypt->add('bob')->bcrypt_b64digest;
```

From https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::Bcrypt#bcrypt_b64digest

> Same as "digest", but will return the digest base64 encoded using the
>   alphabet that is commonly used with bcrypt. The length of the returned
>   string will be 31 and will only contain characters from the ranges
>   '0'..'9', 'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '+', and '.'
>
> The base64 encoded string returned is not padded to be a multiple of 4
>   bytes long. Note: This is bcrypt's own non-standard base64 alphabet,
>   It is not compatible with the standard MIME base64 encoding.